# How to search against a deep tree-like structure in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, database

The simplest way to explain my situation is with standard filesystem structure which is close to what I want to accomplish:

```
Folder A
- Folder A2
-- File 1
-- File 2
- File 3
Folder B
- Folder B2
- Folder B3
-- File 4
```

Folder has fields:

```
- _id
- parents (in my case there can actually be multiple!)
```

File has fields

```
- _id
- targetFolder
```

So, basically a file could be very deep in the hierarchy.

How do I search and structure my DB efficiently so that I can have deep folder hierarchies, with any of them having files.

I want to be able to do a query that returns **every file under e.g. Folder A**. How could I do this?

Answer (score 5):

I recommend the MongoDb official documentation of this [topic](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures/). Storing trees in database is non trivial and every solution have its pro and cons.
I experienced successfully materialized paths model, which is very efficient on hierachy search but expensive on tree modification because you have to update every descendant node.

Answer (score 2):

Not store them as a tree in mongo, at all! Like Lucas said, [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures/) is a good explanation on how you do it.
But your problem is that you need a chained join from the root to Folder A. You could do something like:

```
{ _id, name, type, parent: { grandparent : { parentOfGrandparent : {..........
```

So to search for all files of Folder A you search for all files that parent is "Folder A".
I think this will work:

```
db.files.find( { parent : { "Folder A : { $exists: true } } } );
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do following schema:

Collection name files:

```
{
 _id:id1 (generated unique id),
 name: file2
 type: file
 parents:[id2,id3] -> parent directories FolderA2,FolderA 
}
{
 _id:id2 (generated unique id),
 name: folderA2
 type: directory
 parents:[id3]
}
{
 _id:id3 (generated unique id),
 name: folderA
 type: directory
 parents:[] 
}
```

Then you can build a multikey index on parents and do a query like this :
db.files.find({"parents":"id3","type":"file"}) to find every file under folder A. Downside of this schema is complex inserts since when adding a new file or folder(directory) parents must be filled by getting ids of parents from neighbour files or directories.

Hope this helps